# Strange sqlite behavior

Tags: sqlite

Whole code is too long so i take some part for understanding this case:

```
CREATE TABLE contacts ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, server TEXT NOT NULL, expiredaytime TEXT)

DELETE FROM contacts WHERE server=? AND expiredate is nor null OR expiredate != '' AND expiredate<=date('now')
```

This deletes all recording in table after execution and doesn't metter what data 'expiredate' colum have. But i need to remove only record which have expired date in colum 'expiredate' and don't touch other records whose colums 'expiredate' contain not expired date or empty string or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition is interpreted like this:

```
WHERE (server=? AND expiredate IS NOT NULL)
   OR (expiredate != '' AND expiredate <= date('now'))
```

If you want to group the conditions in a different way, you have to insert appropriate parentheses yourself.

Comment: Thx. And if i write 'expiredaytime TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT \"\"' i can skip this check 'expiredate IS NOT NULL' ?

Comment: Er, what else do you think NOT NULL means?